# Where to run async method in Asp Net Core service

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core

I have a Service which has to keep a live connection to a database.This connection has to be instantiated before any client-request.

Since the Database API provides an async method for connecting to it  where can i connect to the database before any request is issued?

**SocketMiddleware**:

```
class SocketMiddleware
    {
        Handler handler;
        public SocketMiddleware(Handler _handler,RequestDelegate del)
        {
            this.handler = _handler;
            this.next = del;
        }

        RequestDelegate next;

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {

            if (!context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                await  this.next(context);
                return;
            }
            await this.handler.AddClientAsync(context.WebSockets);

        }
    }
```

**Service** that uses a live `RethinkDB` connection:

```
 class Handler
        {

            private readonly RethinkDB r;
            public  Connection Con { get; private set; }

            private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Client> clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Client>();
            private object Lock = new object();

            public Handler()
            {
                this.r = new RethinkDB();
               //I have to instnatiate --- this.Con = this.r.Connection().Port(Constants.RETHINK_PORT).Hostname(Constants.HOST_NAME).ConnectAsync();
            }
              ///////////////////////////---Where can i run the below method?
            public async Task ConnectRethinkAsync()
            {
                using (Process proc = new Process())
                {
                    proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Constants.RETHINK_PROCESS_PATH);
                    proc.Start();


                    this.Con = await this.r.Connection().Port(Constants.RETHINK_PORT).Hostname(Constants.HOST_NAME).ConnectAsync();
                }

            }
            public async Task AddClientAsync(WebSocketManager manager)
            {
                WebSocket clientSocket = await manager.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                string clientID = Ext.MakeId();
                using (Client newClient = Client.Create(clientSocket, clientID))
                {

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (!newClient.KeepAlive)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        ReadOnlyMemory<byte>received = await newClient.ReceiveAsync();
                        string toSend =  $"From Server:\r\nDate:{DateTime.Now.ToString()},WasReceived:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received.ToArray())}\r\nEnd of Message\r\n";
                       // await r.Db(Constants.DB_NAME).Table(Constants.TABLE_NAME).RunAsync(this.Con);
                        await newClient.SendAsync(toSend);
                    }
                }



            }
            public bool RemoveClient(string ID)
            {
                if (this.clients.TryRemove(ID, out Client value))
                {
                    value.Dispose();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }

        }
```

P.S: In the above snippet the most important line is the one with the comment:I need to instantiate the **Connection** which is an async operation.
I can not instantiate it in the `Handler` ctor ,nor in the `SocketMiddleware` ctor .
 The `Con` must be initialized before any request is performed.(in our case - `AddClientAsync` is called)
Should the database connection be done in another service?

Comment: Lazy initialize the connection withing the target method. It will initialize on first invoke and return the connection on subsequent calls.

Comment: What do you mean by lazy? It is null unless i call its `Connection.ConnectAsync` method.It is null otherwise.The object that gets returned by the methods `Port` and `Hostname` is not of type `Connection`.Only when i run the `ConnectAsync` i get the `Connection`.

Comment: And the wrapper method that i created around the connection has no place to be called except on every client request which i do not want/need.

Answer (score 0):

Because you already protected the connection to be set from outside, you can instatiate the connection in  `AddClientAsync` like:

```
if(this.Con == null)
{
    this.Con = await this.r.Connection()
           .Port(Constants.RETHINK_PORT)
           .Hostname(Constants.HOST_NAME)
           .ConnectAsync();
}
```

Comment: But i didn't want to taint the `AddClientAsync` domain since it is another concern.The `Connection` to the database is done once when creating the `Handler` while the `AddClientAsync` is performed for every `websocket` accept.Is there no other place to inject the `Connection` inside the `Handler` class (maybe  higher in the hierarchy in the `Startup` class particularily in `Configure` or `ConfigureServices`?I am asking because in the future the `Handler` might need other dependencies in order for it to function.

Comment: What I'd do then is Refactor the connection logic into it's own async method. then you can call it from the middleware just before `handler.AddClientAsync`

Comment: But that still couples it with every HTTP/TCP request inside the `Invoke` method.I would still have to place a little `if() ...`  that gets evaluated inside every `Invoke()` call.

Comment: That if statement can be inside of the new connection method